# android using margins across multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, screen

Hi I have created an app that i want to run across multiple screens i built the whole thing at HDPi. and when I run it on a newer android phone with a bigger screen the alignment of stuff is out. I know this is because i have set margins to position things using DP.

My question is whats the best practices for using margins across multiple screen sizes and/or is there some code that I can set that can divide/multiply the DP based on screen size?

I'm wanting to get the app across as many devices as possible. but this is my first app so not entirely sure how to do this. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

heres an example of my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tablecell"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
     >

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:text="@string/POS"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TeamName"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dip"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@string/Team"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/played"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TeamName"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TeamName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TeamName"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/won"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/played"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/played"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/played"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/won"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/won"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/won"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goalsFor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lost"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lost"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lost"
        android:gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goalsAgainst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/goalsFor"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/goalsFor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/goalsFor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Difference"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/goalsAgainst"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/goalsAgainst"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/goalsAgainst"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Difference"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Difference"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Difference"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

screens hdpi

[image: hdpi]

screens xhdpi

[image: xhdpi]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well the whole point of using DP is so that you don't have to worry about this. Margins will be roughly the same across devices, but if you're relying on lining things up on one particular device resolution/density combination, you'll definitely be in for a surprise when you test on other devices.

That said, if you do need to specify different margins for different screen sizes, simply add an XML file in `res/values` -- something like `dimens.xml`:

```
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <dimen name="my_view_margin">10dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then add one of these XMLs for every specific device qualifier that you need to (e.g. `values-large`, `values-sw600dp`, `values-xlarge`, etc.) and modify the value as you see fit. When you want to use these dimensions in a layout, just use:

```
android:layout_margin="@dimen/my_view_margin"
```

And Android will pick the correct value for whatever device it happens to be running on.

Comment: you see it's interesting you say that because thats why i put them in dp because i thought thats what should do for example on my project on the hdpi phone a text view is aligned nice and the xhdpi its moved to the left

Comment: I doubt it's your margins then, it's probably something else in your layout causing the misalignment.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: i have added my layout i'm just added the screenshots now

Comment: Oh...there's kind of a lot wrong with that (no offense). You might want to look into a TableLayout for that. For one thing, if you have your TextView set to wrap_content, gravity has no effect (as the frame is the same size as the content). Plus, your margins seem fairly arbitrary, and would only work on the one screen you're testing on. My advice would be to look into TableLayout.

Comment: no offense taken id rather do it right. how could i use a table layout in this case?

Comment: That's a fairly broad question. I'd just start with reading the [`TableLayout` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html), play around with it a bit, and then post any specific questions you find yourself with. Good luck. :)